# Group and Label with trip Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have products that are shipped in and go through processing and shipped out. They sometimes come back and go through processing again. I need to label each trip with a number. I thought about using using a cursor but it would be cumbersome and might not be accurate enough. Need help. See sample below:

```
Item    Date    Process       Trip
1   2/1/2017    Received In    1
1   2/2/2017    Change1        1
1   2/3/2017    Change2        1
1   2/4/2017    Change3        1
1   2/5/2017    Shipped Out    1
1   2/15/2017   Received In    2
1   2/18/2017   Change1        2
1   2/22/2017   Shipped Out    2
2
2
2
```

Comment: is not clear your question .. the sample provided what mean ?   ..

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please more clear in what output you want.

Comment: I'm on SQL Server. What I need is to supply the trip number in the trip column using received in and shipped out as starting and ending points for each trip. Sorry I wasn't clearer in my question.

Comment: How accurate are these logged process events? Is it possible that a "Received In" event could be delayed from being logged to this table or possibly not logged at all? If so, that could create a ripple effect of incorrectly assigned trip numbers that would be difficult to correct given the trip number assignment you are trying to implement.

Comment: Actually, no. If there are no received in event logged a staff would be prevented from performing any other type of events until a received in event has been performed.

Comment: Does the staff always get the received in item number correct? No transposed digits or 2's changed to 5's or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Received In` is always the first process for each item, you can use a running sum to assign trip numbers. Resetting trip to the next number each time a `Received In` is encountered for a given item (based on ascending order of date).

```
select t.*
,sum(case when process='Received In' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by item order by date_column) as trip
from t
```

I assume your version of SQL Server supports `SUM() OVER()` function.

Edit: To update the Trip column, you can use a `cte` to calculate the running sum and update it.

```
with cte as (select t.*
             ,sum(case when process='Received In' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by item order by date_column) as trip_column
             from t)
update cte
set trip=trip_column
```

Comment: I like the fact that this answer does not need to add a "Trip" column to the table referenced in the question.

Comment: Thanks. This works with a tweak. It added a trip column but I already have one but the tweak was minimal. You rock.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. While I do get the correct trip number in the "trip" column created in the statement, I couldn't reference this column as it always comes up invalid column name. I have changed the name and have tried temporary tables, copied the contents to another table to reference the column and I get the same invalid name error. I refreshed Intellisense cache and tried every trick I know and nothing. My intention is to have the already present trip column filled in with the result of the statement, not create a new column. An update statement would be perfect but wasn't working.

Comment: Yes. That would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Worked perfectly. You still rock.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine as is but you might want to create a TripType table rather than using a simple increment.  This would be especially useful for the user.

I'd also look at preventing a 1 to be inserted if there are already higher trips for the item in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid adding a "Trip" column to the Process Log table that you reference in your question. Doing so I fear would lead to data inconsistencies due to irregular process events and unexpected updates to the table.

Instead, I would pursue a means in which you are always able to generate the applicable trip number value given the data contents in this table, the item number of interest and a date reference.

Consider the use of a [SQL-Server scalar function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) to encapsulate the get trip number logic. (The following image shows where scalar functions are stored for a SQL Server 2008 R2 system.)
[image]

Such a function might be called "fnGetTripNum" with two input arguments: item number and date. Passing the item number of "1" and the date of "2/18/2017", then this function should return a trip number of "2" per your data table. (You may want to utilize vkp's SQL syntax recommendation to implement this function.)

The upside to a SQL-Server function is that it provides a way to encapsulate business logic so that it can be applied consistently to several queries that use the function(s).