# SQL Server - Multiple Identity Ranges in the Same Column

Tags: sql-server, grouping, auto-increment, identity

Yesterday, I was asked the same question by two different people. Their tables have a field that groups records together, like a year or location. Within those groups, they want to have a unique ID that starts at 1 and increments up sequentially. Obviously, you could search for `MAX(ID)`, but if these applications have a lot of traffic, they'd need to lock the entire table to ensure the same ID wasn't returned multiple times. I thought about using sequences but that would mean dynamically creating a sequence for each group.

### Example 1:

Records created during the year should increment by one and then restart at 1 at the beginning of the next year.

```
| Year | ID |
|------|----|
| 2016 |  1 |
| 2016 |  2 |
| 2017 |  1 |
| 2017 |  2 |
| 2017 |  3 |
```

### Example 2:

A company has many locations and they want to generate a unique ID for each customer, combining a the location ID with a incrementing ID.

```
| Site | ID |
|------|----|
| XYZ  |  1 |
| ABC  |  1 |
| XYZ  |  2 |
| XYZ  |  3 |
| DEF  |  1 |
| ABC  |  2 |
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: This just sounds like a really bad idea from a data perspective. What happens when a row is deleted? Do you need to renumber everything or are gaps ok? Autonumbering groups with restarts at certain points is one of those things that comes up sometimes and it is almost always a sign of a bad design elsewhere.

Comment: Is there a straight-forward way to generate these IDs? I'd like to make sure the solution works well in a high-traffic environment. Is there's something out-of-the-box for this or is it bizarre enough that it will require something by-hand.

Comment: @SeanLange I guess it is supposed to be like an identity column, that just increments indefinitely, even if a record is deleted.

Comment: @SeanLange Also, I get the impression this wouldn't be the primary key, per se. It is just a user-friendly identifier. I guess the idea is that using a group will keep the numbers fairly small (5 or so digits) to make it easier for users.

Comment: Unless you need these values to persist why not just use ROW_NUMBER?  Partition by Site, TheYearColumn, Order by SomeColumn

Comment: @SeanLange That would work so long as records were never deleted. I'd guess if deletes happened, they'd be soft deletes.

Comment: So is there a question here still?

Comment: @Travis-Parks Take a look at a recent [SO entry - "Group and Label with trip Number"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258448/group-and-label-with-trip-number/42261044#42261044). It may be applicable to your situation.

Comment: @JohnH I would suggest avoiding scalar function as much as possible and I don't think you would need one for this.

Answer (score 0):

One trick that is often under-used is to create a clustered index on Site / ID or Year / ID - BUT Change the order of the ID column to Desc rather than ASC.
This way when you need to scan the CI to get the Next ID value it only needs to check 1 row in the clustered index. I've used this on Multi-Billion Record tables and it runs quite quickly. You can get even better performance by partitioning the table by Site or Year then you'll get the added benefit of partition elimination when you run your MAX(ID) queries.